# HTML date giving "The specified value 'MM/dd/yyyyy' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd' " only on windows OS

Tags: javascript, html, windows, date, windows-11

The code is written in Vue 2 and when the component is mounted it sets the date of the variables of **from** and **to**.

**from** is initialized with month's first date while **to** with the current date. The code was working fine a week ago and is still working fine on my machine which runs Linux. But on clients PC which run windows 11 it is giving

`The specified value "2/17/2023" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"`

because of this on date has to be selected manually.

I've tried setting date with **toISOString()** method

```js
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
// this.from = firstDay.toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
var from = firstDay.toISOString().substring(0, 10)
console.log(from)
```

I've also checked for specific date format with regex and if true converted it to converted it to asked format and also changed the date format of client PC to yyyy-MM-dd but still not working.

Comment: Your ISO version is correct. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: You can get the first day of the month more simply with `let firstDay = new Date(); firstDay.setDate(1);`. *toISOString* returns UTC values, so for systems with a positive offset (or negative ECMAScript/POSIX offset), the UTC date will be the day prior.

Comment: Oh, the CLDR recently changed the format of en-CA from y-MM-dd to M/d/y thus proving that *toLocaleString* is a really bad way to format dates if you need a particular format with any certainty. Yes, I realise that line is commented out. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In early 2023, the major browsers (Safari so far excepted) have picked up [bug 16399](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-16399) introduced during 2022 into the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository. The bug has set `en-CA` numeric date format to American date format instead of the Canadian standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

A workaround until unicode and the browsers are fixed is to use "fr-CA" date format instead, for numeric dates.